# tableview.reload not working after array.removeAll() is called swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

i have a tableview that is not removing data from the cell after i remove all items from array and call tableview.reloadata, in the tableview cell i have a single label and the text stays

gameScore is an instance of my class, that has a func to remove all items from array

```
func reset(winnerPlayer: String){

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Winner:" + " " + "\(winnerPlayer)", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
            print("Tapped")

            self.gameScore.resetArrays()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.teamA_tableview.reloadData()
            }

        }))
```

i call the func using the delegate method on another viewcontroller

```
if teamA_totalScore >= winningScore {
                        print("Winner")
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        delegate?.reset(winnerPlayer: (delegate?.gameScore.teamA_name)!)

                    }
                }else{
                    delegate?.teamA_totalScore.text = ""
                }
```

this is my popUp view controller where declare the Delegate

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var whiteView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var teamsNameSegControl: UISegmentedControl!
        @IBOutlet weak var pointsTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

        var winningScore = Int()

        weak var delegate: GameScoreViewController?

      ....
}
```

this is my gameScore view controller and where i set the delegate

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toPopUp"{
        let popUpView = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
        popUpView.delegate = self

    }
```

i"m calling the reset func that is in my gameScore view controller from my popUp view controller

this is my tableview delegate and datasource, i'm only using teamA_tableView to test the func reset, i did tried using both and teamB_tableview but didn't work aswell

```
extension GameScoreViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var numberOfRows = Int()

        if tableView == teamA_tableview{
            numberOfRows = gameScore.teamA_points.count

        }else if tableView == teamB_tableview{
            numberOfRows = gameScore.teamB_points.count
        }

        return numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == teamA_tableview {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamA_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreTableViewCell
            cell.teamA_label.text = String(gameScore.teamA_points[indexPath.row])

        }else if tableView == teamB_tableview {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamB_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreBTableViewCell
             cell.teamB_label.text = String(gameScore.teamB_points[indexPath.row])
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: How is the `delegate` set?  Is it pointing at the correct instance of the view controller?  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to confirm that `delegate` isn't `nil`?

Comment: i did, and both "print" statements do print, i used a breakpoint, and it works as well

Comment: But is it the correct instance of your view controller?  A common mistake is not setting the delegate correctly and so you aren't interacting with the instance that is on screen.  Can you show the code where you set the delegate?

Comment: i edited, check it out @Paulw11

Comment: Ok.  Can you show your code for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`

Comment: just did @Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200874/discussion-between-paulw11-and-scs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == teamA_tableview {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamA_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreTableViewCell
            cell.teamA_label.text = String(gameScore.teamA_points[indexPath.row])

        } else if tableView == teamB_tableview {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamB_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreBTableViewCell
             cell.teamB_label.text = String(gameScore.teamB_points[indexPath.row])
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

I don't know how it works before reload data, by the look of your cellForRowAtIndexpath, you are returning a new UITableViewCell() instance but not your ScoreTableViewCell or ScoreBTableViewCell

should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == teamA_tableview {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamA_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreTableViewCell
            cell.teamA_label.text = String(gameScore.teamA_points[indexPath.row])
            return cell

        } else if tableView == teamB_tableview {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamB_scoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ScoreBTableViewCell
             cell.teamB_label.text = String(gameScore.teamB_points[indexPath.row])
             return cell
        } else {
             return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Additionally a recommendation: Both for A team's score and B team's score you should probably have the same cell and not two different kind of cells something like ScoreTableviewCell. You just change the team name, jersey, color, etc.

Comment: got it working now, thank you so much for your help